# Attempting to load a 64-bit application, how this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit mode

Tags: intel, virtual-pc

I have a Dell Studio 540, 64 bit OS Windows Home Premium. My CPU is supports Intel's virtualization technology, but I don't know how to enabled it on my machine. I saw that you can do it via the bios, but I didn't see this option when going through my BIOS. Is there another way to enabled this feature? Please let me know. I'm trying to installed Windows Server 2008 via Vircutal PC 2007.

Thank You,

Comment: On VirtualBox those sorts of options were selectable when creating a new virtual machine. So I'd start Virtual PC 2007, create a new virtual machine into which to install Server 2008 and see if those options are available somewhere.

Comment: @Amos, I could not find the option to enable this feature. My cpu supports intel virtualization technology. Do you think the problem is that I'm trying to installed a 64 server 2008 on my 64 os machine? Should I try a 32 bit server 2008? My end goal is to run sharepoint 2007 on this machine....

Comment: @ChrisF, what do you mean by Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: I meant that this question would be better suited to Server Fault or Super User, but I'm not sure which one. Sorry for being cryptic but the comment was really aimed at those with close votes. If people agree with me it will get migrated automatically so you don't have to do anything other than have a linked account on the target site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual PC does not support x64 guests regardless of the host operating system or CPU.  You'll need to choose a different virtualization tool if you want x64 guests.

Comment: My end goal is to have Windows Server 2008 with SharePoint2007 and Sql Server 2008 installed. Can I make this work work, with 32 bit versions, where my machine is 64bit.

Comment: If you have 32-bit versions of those products you should be able to get them to work in Virtual PC. Microsoft's level of support for server software on Virtual PC isn't universal (for example, I think that only the 'Standard' SKU of Server 2008 is supported), but being unsupported doesn't necessarily mean it won't work (though x64 guest support is right out).

Comment: I think I might go back to Windows Server 2003, since I can't find a 32 bit version of windows server 2008 to download, and just install SharePoint 2007 and Sql Server 2005 32bit

Comment: @Brandon: you might also consider VMware or one of the other virtualization tools - for the most part they support 64-guests if your CPU supports them.

Comment: this might be a stupid questions? What is the difference between 32 and 64 bit and can you run software that is 64 onto a 32 bit machine?